# Are there any written or oral OT guidelines on who the 'poor' are?

Tags: old-testament, economics

We had a discussion about giving to the poor as many Christians tend to do.  Our small group had a big argument on who qualifies as "the poor".  Some said it is anyone in need, others said is only believers who are struggling, and then some picked places in the middle to stand.

Basically we were just all giving our opinions and had to solid ground to stand on.

Sometimes I feel like the whole idea isn't about the poor, but rather me.  That by giving I show care for others, I trust God to care for me, I show others God cares for them, that I'm not attached to material things or making an idol out of them by hoarding, etc.  Are there any details on "the poor" in the old testament?  I ask because, if the bible doesn't focus on who the poor are or try to qualify them, then maybe I shouldn't either.

Maybe there is something back in the Pentateuch which I have not read all of.  **Do you know any Old Testament passages that help define who the poor are?**

**Is there any Jewish oral history that relates to this topic?**

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question. There aren't many options, and it sounds like you've covered both of them: "People in need" and "Christians in need." If you're looking for something more than this, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I'd assume there is a difference between people caught in their own sin and in need vs people who are suffering from the sinful choices of others and are in need.  Further I'd expect some clarification on if it matters how the 'giving' is used and if there is any expectation that the giver have or develop a relationship with the person in need.  Finally is giving believed to be a material concept, or does spirituality come into play.  My question has defined some definitions of how to answer the question, but not what any given denomination has determined the answer to be.

Comment: Those may be reasonable questions, but that's not what you've asked. Further, most of those questions must be scoped to a very specific denomination to be answerable here.

Comment: I might suggest something like "Are there any denominations which believe Christians ought to only give to the poor who are poor by no fault of their own?" or "What is the justification for giving to the poor who are poor due to their own sin?" or something along these lines. This would narrow your question to be more answerable and specific, while, I believe, still getting to the core of your question. And you may wish to ask more than one such question to get different perspectives.

Comment: I guess I slipped over to the other side of the question on the giving instead of 'the poor' when writing my comment.  Still, I did specify what are the views of who the poor are and which definition of the poor they believe we are to give to.  I see my question as a simple matrix of types of the poor on the top and should we give on the side.  One matrix per denomination would be valid answers.  Is that not a direct and answerable question in your mind?

Comment: No, I don't see that as a direct and answerable question. I see it as incredibly broad. I also suspect that these differing definitions likely aren't limited by denominational boundaries. In my (perhaps limited) personal experience, those who are likely to make a big deal about such distinctions are conservative, right-wing American Christians, and are likely to co-exist in a denomination with others who don't make such distinctions. When I've had conversations reminiscent of what I imagine happened in your small group, for instance, they were typically among members of the same church, and...

Comment: ...thus the same denomination. Perhaps your SG is inter-denominational, but if its not, then your SG proves my point, too. In other words, the opinions on this issue are usually far more personal than they are denominational. So your idea of a matrix-by-denomination probably wouldn't do the issue justice... (that's one point). Second, even if it were possible to delineate the views by some other metric, I suspect there are far too many to fit into a neat matrix.  Perhaps there can be a spectrum--but as I've already mentioned, you seem to have already identified both ends of this spectrum in...

Comment: ...your question (one end: "All in need", other end: "Christians in need").

Comment: In summary, my view is that this issue is too messy to address in a "summary" question, beyond what you have already summarized in your question. Anything else requires more specific questions.

Comment: And a personal observation, which may be entirely off base: Those I've met who have made the distinction at all have seemed to do so out of, what I perceive to be, a warped sense of self-preservation and entitlement, not out of a heart of helping. Put another way: It's an search for an excuse *not* to help those people which are deemed "unworthy" by a personal standard, rather than a heart of love and charity, which Christ demonstrated. If at all accurate, finding a denominational justification for the view to only help "Christians in need" may be difficult (but I won't say it doesn't exist.)

Comment: I appreciate your viewpoint and perhaps it is too messy.  We could wait and see if there are any responses instead of jumping to conclusions.  As an aside, of course there are people who fit the stereotype you mentioned, but it is still a stereotype that doesn't fit everyone - even remotely.  Many Christians genuinely want to understand how to help others - for instance many older parents have realized that the only way to help their lazy children was to stop giving to them.  Basically giving isn't just blindly handing out stuff, thought needs to be behind it.  In our country there is so...

Comment: much help, food, clothing, medical assistance available it is probably a good idea to have a well thought out and deeper understanding of what USA poor is vs 3rd world poor and how someone with funds can most wisely use them to help those in need.  Wisdom comes from many sources, like scripture and those who have studied it in depth may be able to share their finding or experience here on this forum in my question.  Your past experience with 1 sterotype doesn't mean my question and the response of others will fit that same mold.

Comment: I appreciate (and agree with) your response to my "observation," but I think it only complicates things. You're no longer identifying "the poor," but now you're asking how one ought to give to them. If anything, that only makes the question broader, not more specific.

Comment: And yes, we'll see how others respond. I was just offering my perspective, in case it was able to help you narrow the focus of your question.

Comment: I do appreciate your input to tailor my question. Making a good question is important, and I do see your point.  You're probably right about the responses as you have my experience on the forum than I do.

Comment: This question is certainly quite broad, and might require a book to answer given its many facets. Fortunately, such a book has been written: _[Ministries of Mercy](http://www.amazon.com/Ministries-Mercy-Call-Jericho-Road/dp/0875522173)_ by Tim Keller.